# fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_serialization.lib'

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2010, boost, boost-serialization

I made a Qt application using boost serialization that builds perfectly on MacOS and Linux. Now I'm trying to build it on Windows using MSVC 2010.
I'm using Qt5.5.0 msvc2010, boost 1.55.0 msvc2010 binaries downloaded from sourceforge.

The serialization shared libraries that I have are:

```
boost_serialization-vc100-1_55.dll
boost_serialization-vc100-1_55.lib
boost_serialization-vc100-gd-1_55.dll
boost_serialization-vc100-gd-1_55.lib
boost_serialization-vc100-mt-1_55.dll
boost_serialization-vc100-mt-1_55.lib
boost_serialization-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.dll
boost_serialization-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib
```

There is no `boost_serialization.lib`.

In the .pro file I defined the boost macro:

```
DEFINES += BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK
```

and I'm linking the library in this way:

```
LIBS += -L"$$PWD/../libs/boost-1.55.0/windows/lib" -lboost_serialization
```

but I still get the error.
I don't know how to solve this problem.

Any idea?

Comment: Try linking it this way `LIBS += -L"$$PWD/../libs/boost-1.55.0/windows/lib" -lboost_serialization-vc100-1_55` Also if you are using QtCreator try [library add wizard](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html).

Comment: @Eligijus Now I get the following errors: `boost-1.55.0\include\boost/fusion/iterator/detail/adapt_value_traits.hpp(18) : fatal error C1060: compiler is out of heap space`, `boost/fusion/support/iterator_base.hpp(28) : fatal error C1060: compiler is out of heap space`

Comment: I solved the heap space error... Now I get many of those errors: `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class QVector<class myclass1 *> const & __thiscall myclass_derived::method(void) const " (?method@myclass_derived@@UBEABV?$QVector@PAVmyclass1@@@@XZ)`